# magento 2 admin grid not clickable in ui component

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, grid

I am using Magento 2.1.7 version. I have created a custom admin grid module. It is listing out the grid, But I can't click row to edit action.
I followed [this link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. i added code
app/code/[vendername]/[modulename]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/mohan_listing.xml

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="[vendername]\[modulename]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostAction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

and i create new file
[vendername][modulename]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostAction.php

```
namespace [vendername]\[modulename]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class PostAction extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['blogpost_id'])) {
                    $viewUrlPath = $this->getData('config/viewUrlPath') ?: '#';
                    $urlEntityParamName = $this->getData('config/urlEntityParamName') ?: 'blogpost_id';
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'view' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                $viewUrlPath,
                                [
                                    $urlEntityParamName => $item['blogpost_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

It working fine